# Can someone explain the integral split in the following?

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{G}$ where $\mathbb{G}$ is the filtration progressively enlarged by the filtration $\mathbb{F}$ and let $\tau$ be a $\mathbb{G}$-stopping time.

Define $B_t:= \exp (\int_0^t r_s ds)$ where $r$ is $\mathbb{G}$-adapted and let $A$ be a $\mathbb{G}$-adapted process with finite variation, can some one explain the following equality?

$$B_\tau\mathbb{E} \bigg[\int_{[\tau,T]} (B_s)^{-1} dA_s \bigg| \mathcal{G}_\tau \bigg]= A_\tau - A_{\tau-} + B_\tau\mathbb{E} \bigg[\int_{(\tau,T]} (B_s)^{-1} dA_s \bigg| \mathcal{G}_\tau \bigg]$$

How does the right hand side change if $r$ and\or $A$ were $\mathbb{F}$-adapted?

Comment: $B_\tau \mathsf{E}[\int_{[\tau,T]}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s| \mathcal{G}_\tau]
=B_\tau \mathsf{E}[B_{\tau}^{-1}\Delta A_{\tau}| \mathcal{G}_\tau ]
+ B_\tau \mathsf{E}[\int_{(\tau,T]}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s| \mathcal{G}_\tau]$

Comment: @JGWang
Is there a general rule where you can take out the lower bound of the integral like that? Can you refer a book or website?

Comment: Thank you for your replication, I write an answer as following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s$ is a (stochastic) integral by path,
it is also a Lebesgue-Stieljes type integral, then
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{[a,b]}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}1_{[a,b]}(s)B_s^{-1}\,dA_s,\quad 0\le a\le b<\infty,
\end{equation*}
Meanwhile, $1_{[\tau,T]}(s)=1_{[\tau,\tau]}(s)+1_{(\tau,T]}(s) $, then
\begin{align*}
 \int_{[\tau,T]}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}1_{[\tau,T]}(s)B_s^{-1}\,dA_s\\
 &=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}1_{[\tau,\tau]}(s)B_s^{-1}\,dA_s
 +\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}1_{(\tau,T]}(s)B_s^{-1}\,dA_s\\
 &=B_{\tau}^{-1}\Delta A_{\tau}+\int_{(\tau,T]}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
 B_\tau \mathsf{E}[\int_{[\tau,T]}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s| \mathcal{G}_\tau]
=B_\tau \mathsf{E}[B_{\tau}^{-1}\Delta A_{\tau}| \mathcal{G}_\tau ]
+ B_\tau \mathsf{E}[\int_{(\tau,T]}B_s^{-1}\,dA_s| \mathcal{G}_\tau]
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.